# NullPointerException on View.PerformClick on BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash

I'm getting a lot of crashes on this in my production application. I have not been able to reproduce it myself, and the crash stack trace does not mention any of my own files. As you can see on the crash overview, I get the same crash many different places.

Is this a bug in the bottom navigation library? Has anyone else experienced this?

[image: Stack trace]
[image: Crash list]

Comment: You have to replicate this to debug, have you tried this on multiple devices/OS?

Comment: Hello, I guess before initialize the UI, if we access that view it will show this exception.

Comment: Looks very weird. Would be great if you show how you initialize and setup your BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: Are you calling `popBackStack()` in your app and not checking the return result [as the docs say you should](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack)? It sounds like you've popped every destination off the back stack

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have not checked the return result on popBackStack() - I will test this! Thanks :)